# JAVA Type Parameter in Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, inner-classes

Java type parameter declaration as a part of inner class.

The question I have is on linked list.  I am seeing the same thing in `ArrayList` implementation.

```
public class LinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E> {....

private class LinkedIterator implements Iterator<E>{...} //inner class of LinkedList

private static class ListNode<E> //implemented as nested static class
```

Question:
Why does the iterator (and constructor for LinkedList) both do not require  type parameter,
I think listNode requires  because static class make it can not access class header of the outter
class.

Comment: The inner (non-static) class belongs to an instance of the outer class, so the generic type is decided by that.

Answer (score 2):

Any class definition that is:

- Inside another class definition.
- **not** marked `static`

is an inner class. Conceptually, the class exists only within a single instance of the outer class. Effectively, it means this:

- There is a hidden, private, and final field of the outer type. All constructors require an instance of outer, but java syntax is special to pass it: `outerRef.new Inner();` - and if you are in a context where `Outer.this` would be sensible, that is the default value. This field does not have a getter.
- All type params of the outer class are also available in the inner class unless shadowed.

So, given that `private class LinkedIterator` is inside `class LinkedList`, it is this kind of inner class, it has that hidden field, and it inherits the `<E>` from `LinkedList<E>`. The Node, however, is `static`, therefore it does not have that field and does not inherit the `<E>` - instead choosing to declare it itself.

Note that inner classes are complicated and surprising. They can for example mess up garbage collecting (because they hold a reference to their outer; that will prevent gc of the outer, for example). As a general rule, if you're not sure, strongly prefer static inner classes, making any inheritance of either an instance of outer or its generics explicit.

In other words:

```
public class Outer<E> {
    public class Inner {}
}
```

is tricky; don't do that unless you're sure the concept of being an inner class fully applies. If you don't know what that means or aren't sure, write this instead:

```
public class Outer<E> {
    public static class Inner<E> {
        private final Outer<E> context;

        public Inner(Outer<E> context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
    }
}
```

omitting all parts you don't need, of course.